# $.extend functionality doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: jquery

I have written a small plugin to change the text size but it doesn't seem to work properly.
$('#mypara').changeTextSize('30px'); doesn't set the size to 30px but instead sets to 10px

### jquery.myPlugin.js

```
jQuery.fn.changeTextSize = function(size){
alert(size);    //shows 30px        

var config = {
    'size' : '10px'
};
if(size) {
    $.extend(config,size);
}

alert(config.size); //shows 10px

return $(this).each(function() {
    $(this).css('font-size',config.size);
});

};
```

### HTML

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery.myPlugin.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mypara').changeTextSize('30px');    
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="mypara">dsfdsfdsf</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Is your `'` after `alert(size)'`  really in your code ? it should be `;`

Comment: thanks evilP! but it was a typo mistake while pasting it here.. but still its not solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function is used to merge *objects*. You are trying to merge a string, `size`, into an object literal, `config`. You would need to pass an object as the argument to your plugin:

```
$('#mypara').changeTextSize({
    size: '30px'
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/YDegf/).

Alternatively, if that's the only argument and there's not going to be more options, it may be easier to forget about using `extend` at all, and just do something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.changeTextSize = function(size){ 
    return this.css('font-size', size || "10px");
};
```

Notice how I've removed the `each`, since there is no need for it (most jQuery methods apply to every element in the matched set by default), and you also don't need to pass `this` into `jQuery` since it is already an instance of `jQuery`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/YDegf/2/) of that one.

Comment: @user1184100 - No problem, glad I could help :) See my update for a shorter alternative.